# Is there anything faster than readLines in R - OR how do I find out why reading my connection is so slow?

Tags: c, r, sockets

I have a socket connection between c (client) and R (R acts as a server.. using RStudio). C sends a string of 5 numbers in R. For example:

```
1 16.29 3.8 0 0
```

In R I am receiving the string using:

```
    con <- socketConnection(host="localhost", port = 8080, blocking=TRUE,
                        server=TRUE, open="r+")
```

and the next line is:

```
helloTall <- readLines(con,1)
```

The lines are read fine but the problem is that I have to do this very frequently (it is a time step coupling exercise, and so I have to do this > 1000 times, and in some cases more than 500k times).

readLines is extremely slow for this type of work, and readChar is not any better. Is there any other (much) faster way to read the above short string from a connection?

I am using R 3.5.2.

UPDATE: 
Given there is no response yet here is a couple more points. Is there a fast way to read 5 numbers from a socket? My understanding is that these come as a string. readLines takes 1 minute to read these 5 numbers, so with >5000 time steps in my case I would need >5000 minutes!!!

UPDATE 2:
I have now also tried the "scan" for the content of the connection and it is equally slow:

```
hello2<-scan(con, sep=" ")
```

It also takes a minute to read these 5 numbers. Does it mean that con has a lot of nulls or spaces or something that slows down reading its contents? I know almost nothing about connections.

Following a request from one of the comments, I am also publishing the c code which is the client in this case (note the c code in my case is called from a fortran program):

```
// Client side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#define PORT 8080 


/*int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) */
void client_(int *nsinc, double *rTairExch, double *rToutExch, double *rTsolExch, double *ResTair) 
{ 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    int itimensinc = *nsinc;
    double NoBitrTairExch=*rTairExch;
    double NoBitrToutExch=*rToutExch;
    double NoBitrTsolExch=*rTsolExch;
    double NoBitResTair=*ResTair;
    double length = snprintf( NULL, 0, \
                   "%d %.4g %.4g %.4g %.4g", itimensinc,NoBitrTairExch,NoBitrToutExch,NoBitrTsolExch,NoBitResTair,"\n");
    char* str = malloc( length + 1 );
    snprintf( str, length + 1,"%d %.4g %.4g %.4g %.4g",itimensinc,NoBitrTairExch,NoBitrToutExch,NoBitrTsolExch,NoBitResTair,"\n");
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return; 
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n"); 
        return; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return; 
    } 

    send(sock , str , strlen(str) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 

/* Define temporary variables */
    char *eptr;
    double result;
    result = strtod(buffer, &eptr);
    printf("return value\n"); 
    printf("%.2lf",result);
    *ResTair=result;

    return; 
}
```

By the way, I have now posted this also to the R community forum here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-anything-faster-than-readlines-in-r/23346/5

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @d.b : I just need to read one line as fast as I can. The current readLines takes 1 minute to read 1 line with those 5 numbers above!

Comment: Can you also post how the C program is issuing this string of numbers?  R may be waiting for C to close the socket, or the OS may be buffering the write, which would look like what you are describing.

Comment: @PaSTE: Thank you. I have posted it above. Let me know please if you need more details.

Comment: It looks like your C program is the server and your R script is the client.  Is there any particular reason you set `server=TRUE` in the `socketConnection` call?  Are you using the same socket to send data back to the C program?

Comment: @PaSTE: Thank you. My intention was to use R as the server and I do not see how the C program is the client in this case. And yes, I use the same socket to return back data by using "writeLines(as.character(ResultConvertTreturn), con)" (where "ResultConvertTreturn" is the result of computations in R)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C program as written does not send a newline character (`\n`) over the socket.  Your R client is waiting for the newline in order to complete either `readLines` or `scan`, and it does so until it runs into the default [1 minute timeout](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html) for R network connections.

The offending line in the C code is here:

```
snprintf(str, length + 1,
         "%d %.4g %.4g %.4g %.4g",  /* <-- 5 format specifiers */
         itimensinc,NoBitrTairExch,NoBitrToutExch,NoBitrTsolExch,NoBitResTair,  /* <-- 5 things to format */
         "\n");  /* <-- this is never added to str */
```

The C function `snprintf`, like all functions of the `printf` family, will [silently ignore extra arguments that do not fit in the format string.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)

Try either including the newline character in the format string itself, or adding a string or character format specifier:

```
snprintf(str, length + 1,
         "%d %.4g %.4g %.4g %.4g\n",  /* <-- 5 format specifiers and a newline */
         itimensinc,NoBitrTairExch,NoBitrToutExch,NoBitrTsolExch,NoBitResTair);  /* <-- 5 things to format */

/* or */

snprintf(str, length + 1,
         "%d %.4g %.4g %.4g %.4g%c",  /* <-- 6 format specifiers */
         itimensinc,NoBitrTairExch,NoBitrToutExch,NoBitrTsolExch,NoBitResTair,'\n');  /* <-- 6 things to format */
```